# Tuple structural identity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tuples, identity

Also using assertion libraries with methods devoted to comparing list, I'm unable to match this two results in unit tests:

```
var list1 = new List<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
{
  Tuple.Create<string,IEnumerable<string>>("string", new[] { "value" })
};

var list2 = new List<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
{
  Tuple.Create<string,IEnumerable<string>>("string", new[] { "value" })
};


var result = list1.All(a => list2.Any(a.Equals)); // result false
```

The only way to get a positive match is *decomposing* the tuple and matching `Item2` with a method that supports comparison of lists.

There's a way without doing it?

Comment: You can create your own class with overriden equals, then you could use `result = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) extension method:

```
var result = list1.All(a => list2.Any(x => x.Item1 == a.Item1 && x.Item2.SequenceEqual(a.Item2)));
```

Returns `true` for your sample input.

The reason why you have to do it explicitly and it's not working by default when two `Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>` instances are compared is the second `Tuple` item. According to MSDN both components are checked agains each other to decide if `Tuple`s are equal. Because the second one is an `Array` standard reference equality comparer is used. And because your `Tuple`s are not pointing to the same `Array` in memory it returns false.

Stardard `.Any(a.Equals)` would work if only your `Tuple` objects were pointing to the same array:

```
var array = new[] { "value" };

var list1 = new List<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
{
    Tuple.Create<string,IEnumerable<string>>("string", array)
};

var list2 = new List<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
{
    Tuple.Create<string,IEnumerable<string>>("string", array)
};

var result = list1.All(a => list2.Any(a.Equals));
```

Returns `true` as well.

Comment: +1 this works and allow a terse syntax. Also if it decompose tuples, it's ok for me; because it enough synthetic to fit in an `Assert.True`.

Comment: yes I'm agree: this is the reason. I was just wondering if someone wrote some unit test method that cover the case...